# Trouble creating unordered list with number of list items controlled by user input

Tags: javascript, html, function, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I tried to make a function that would generate a number of list items based on the user input from a prompt. It does not work although I believe it should.

I'm looking for an explanation of what's wrong with my code even if an alternate solution is also provided, if possible.

On the HTML side I have entered  `<div class="freshList"></div>` in the body so that it can be picked up by the function and have the list placed in that location

Code is below:

```
function makeAList()
{
var freshList = document.getElementsByClassName("freshList");
var listLength = prompt("Enter number of list items");

var listString = "<ul>"; 
for (var i=0; i < listLength; i++) 
{
    listString+= "<li>"+"</li>"

} 
listString += "</ul>" 
document.innerHTML = listString;  
}

makeAList();

// end code
```

Now the only way I have been able to get this to work was by accident when using the document.Write method at various points in the code to see what was working (I tried console log first which said that the function was called and the loop was proceeding but no output was coming so I switched to doc.write instead). I used document.Write(listString); and this was able to forcibly print the bullet points onto the screen but that is not my desire. I want it in the HTML not just printed on the screen (so that I can manipulate it with other functions I have made).

Altogether I wanted to make a series of functions to perform the following action: Ask if the user would like to make a new list. Call the makeNewList function which would prompt the user for the number of items. Then ask the user if they would like to edit the list and call the editList function with new prompts for each list item. Finally leaving an output of # of bullet points with user input on each point. I am sure this is a ridiculous idea that nobody would use but it was more a lesson for myself to try an idea I had rather than something functional. Full (attempted) code below:

```
function makeAList()
{
var freshList = document.getElementsByClassName("freshList");
var listLength = prompt("Enter number of list items");

var listString = "<ul>";
for (var i=0; i < listLength; i++)
{
    listString+= "<li>"+"</li>"
}
listString += "</ul>"
document.innerHTML = listString;
}

makeAList();


function editAList() {
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            list[i].innerHTML = prompt("Place list text below","")
        }

function checkList(){
var resp1 = confirm("Would you like to make a new list?")
if(resp1 == true)
{
    makeAList();
}
else
{

}
if(resp1 === false){
    var resp2 = prompt("Would you like to edit an existing list instead?")
}
else if(resp2 === true){
    editAList();
}
else{
    alert("You have chosen not to make a new list or edit an existing one")
}

}

checkList();
```

Comment: Problem is: `document.innerHTML = listString;` The `document` has no `.innerHTML` property. Seems like you intended to put the list in the `freshList` element, but didn't. If that's the case, you'd do `freshList[0].innerHTML = listString`

Comment: *"the spaces are put here because it wasn't displaying otherwise for my post"* - If you use back tick ` characters to quote your code it won't be interpreted as HTML. (I've edited your question to fix it; if you click [edit] you can see exactly how that was done.)

Comment: Also, if you wanted the first, perhaps only, `freshList`, then better would be `var freshList = document.querySelector(".freshList")` It returns the first match instead of a collection, so you'd just do `freshList.innerHTML = listString`.

Comment: @squint thank you for your help that was the problem

Comment: @squint if you don't mind I have an unrelated question. In stack overflow why are your responses considered "comments" rather than an "answer"? I see this a lot with questions I look at and the formatting is kind of confusing to understand because of it.

Comment: @vampiire: I do it mostly in defiance of their silly, meaningless reputation system that begets a high level of garbage answers. It's not unusual to immediately see multiple code-only, often mediocre solutions because everyone wants to be first to get points. I'd rather put useful explanations up here. I know, the formatting is terribly hard to read. Just the way it goes.

Comment: @squint ah okay. Interesting that for such a popular tool they have a terribly confusing response system. Especially because it leaves comments collapsed. Ugh is what it is. Thank you again for the help

Comment: Glad I could help. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

My friend looked at my code and made some changes as well as detailed comments with the places I went wrong. For anyone who views this question in the future here is his response. All credit to him but I don't know his stack overflow handle to tag him.

[Here is his js bin updated and heavily commented code](http://jsbin.com/pituvuheka/3/edit?html,js,output)

Code below in case that link dies:

```
// hi
// i've changed a few things, i've left the original code in comments (//)

function makeAList()
{
 // what does the following code return? a single element? a list of elements? 
 //var freshList = document.getElementsByClassName("freshList") 
var freshList = document.getElementById("freshList"); 
var listLength = prompt("Enter number of list items");

//   var listString = "<ul>";
//   you can create a 'ul' element and append the list string later
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.setAttribute('id', 'theList');
// there's an even shorter way of doing all this, but since you're starting           out, we can save that for later
for (var i=0; i < listLength; i++)
{
 //i would probably append here too, but just demonstrating insertAdjacent
 ul.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<li></li>');
}
// document.innerHtml = listString //this was the reason why this function   didn't work
// document has no inner html, instead, you want to append the list to the  .freshList div that you created
// and then append that to the listOfLists that  you queried

// the reason why we don't want to manually set innerHTML is because the DOM has to be reparsed and recreated 
// every time innerHTML is set. if you have 1000s of lists, this would be extremely slow
// there are DOM apis that create and insert html elements much more faster and efficient (appendChild)
// if you want to create html elements as strings, as you have done previously, use insertAdjacentHTML: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML
// it is faster and more efficient
freshList.appendChild(ul);
}

 makeAList();


function editAList() {
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
// there's a much more efficient way to do this, but keep this here for now
var insertText = function(i) {
var input = prompt("Place list text below", "");
console.log(i);
list[i].append(input);
}

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
// why would we use settimeout?    http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

setTimeout(insertText.bind(null, i), 1000); // why bind?     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
}
}

editAList();

// function checkList(){
// var resp1 = confirm("Would you like to make a new list?")
// if(resp1 == true)
// {
//     makeAList();
// }
// else
// {

// }
// if(resp1 === false){
//     var resp2 = prompt("Would you like to edit an existing list instead?")
// }
// else if(resp2 === true){
//     editAList();
// }
// else{
//     alert("You have chosen not to make a new list or edit an existing one")
// }

// }

// checkList();
```